# TFS Project to Repo Relationship

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, alm

We are going to be migrating an existing BizTalk codebase into TFS 2015 update 2. We would like to use GIT rather than TFVC for version control.

I have a problem getting my head around the repo to project relationship. I would like to run independent TFS projects for managing discrete pieces of work that align with "projects" as run by the business. Instinct tells me that I should create a branch for such projects but each TFS project seems to need its own repo?

If I stick with a single (BizTalk) TFS project, I will be able to create a branch for each business project but the work items will all be mixed together. This would make helpful reporting tools such as the burndown chart useless.

I guess the other option is to run multiple TFS projects each with their own repo and then manually merges between the repos? Maybe have a "Main" project and use its repo as the main branch of the project repos?

How are people managing this problem?

Comment: You probably don't want multiple team projects and almost certainly not if you want version control relationships between them.  Some background reading is at https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/, http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx,  and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2014/11/19/many-git-repositories-but-one-team-project-to-rule-them-all/

Answer (score 0):

First note that inside a Team Project you can create several Git repositories.

Also, remember that Git branches have repository scope, it is not a directory like in TFVC (which it is not like Git at all :-) ).

Then if you want to migrate to Git, you need to modularize your projects. Once you have a modular code base, for each module you should create a Git repository. From each repository you should be able to build and publish a Nuget package. Then resolve inter module dependencies by resolving dependencies by means of Nuget package.

No need to merge anything from repo to repo or from module to module :-) You only need to merge from branch to branch inside the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is that you can create multiple repositories in GIT Team Project.

Regarding work items, you may create multiple teams and areas, then put work items in different areas and change area per to requirements (the teams can have the same area).

There is a blog that may benefit you: [Many Git Repositories, but one Team Project to rule them all](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2014/11/19/many-git-repositories-but-one-team-project-to-rule-them-all/)